# how to pass form data from cakephp controller to a non-Cake content while redirect?

Tags: php, cakephp, parameters, cakephp-2.x

I have an instance where I am using Payment Gateway which has non-MVC files and I have to pass data to those files while redirecting from Cakephp which follows MVC architecture. How to acieve this? I dont want to pass data through URL.

Comment: There's no code to clarify this, but exactly why does the design pattern of the app matter? Is this because a redirect is always a GET? Can't you use POST? Perhaps I missed something. An example of your code and the thing you're trying to redirect to would help the question a lot.

Comment: title clarified